# Mysql - concat string with another sql result

Tags: mysql, sql

Since I am new to mysql .

```
select concat ((select to_char(count(*)) from users) ,' of users')  from dual;
(or)
select concat ((select to_char(count(*)) from users) ,' of users')  ;
```

I am expecting "100 of users" as result set output. in oracle, the above-mentioned statement will work , but not in mysql. i am getting result value as 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the following, using [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) (or [`CONCAT_WS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat-ws)) and a [`CAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) to char:

```
-- using CONCAT
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(COUNT(*) AS CHAR), ' of users') FROM users;

-- using CONCAT_WS
SELECT CONCAT_WS(' ', CAST(COUNT(*) AS CHAR), 'of users') FROM users;
```

Instead of `TO_CHAR` you need to use [`CAST(... AS CHAR(5))`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast). Since MySQL 8.0 the [`CONCAT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_concat) can concat the result of `COUNT(*)` and `of users` without a [`CAST`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_cast) or [`CONVERT`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/cast-functions.html#function_convert) (explicit conversion).

> **demo:** https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/3mVqPxrDZHURyMbX6px4L/0

Comment: it is returning Blob

Comment: tried select concat(count(*),' of users') from users;

Answer (score 0):

try below way it will works below is an example not directly yours

```
SELECT CONCAT(CAST(COUNT(*) AS CHAR(5)), ' of users') FROM Vendor;
```

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4704eb/18